# DropdownList in Popup in Grid KendoUI dont show data

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

i have a problem with a DropdownList control.
i have a Grid with a popup edditing and when i show a popup the DropDownList doesnt show any data, im using MVC4 and KendoUI controls

this is the code.

The Grid.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CashControl.Models.Usuario>()
                    .Name("grid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.nombre).Width(100);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.nombreUsuario).Width(100);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.email).Width(100);
                        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(160);
                    })
                    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
                    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("DropDownListUsuarios"))
                    .Pageable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .Scrollable()
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .PageSize(20)
                        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                        .Model(model => 
                            {
                                model.Id(p => p.idUsuario);
                            })
                        .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Grid"))
                        .Read(read => read.Action("UsuariosRead", "Configuracion"))
                        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Grid"))
                        .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Grid"))
                    )
                )
```

The PopUp

```
<div class="demo-section" style="width: 250px;">
    <h2>Products</h2>
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("products")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 250px" })
          .DataTextField("nombre")
          .DataValueField("idnombre")
          .DataSource(source => {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("UsuarioRead", "Configuracion");
              }); 
          })
    )
</div>
<style scoped>
    .demo-section {
        width: 250px;
        margin: 35px auto 50px;
        padding: 30px;
    }
    .demo-section h2 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

and the Controller.

```
public ActionResult UsuarioRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            IQueryable<Usuario> products = CashControl.Usuario;
            var rest = products.Select(n => new
            {
                idUsuario = n.idUsuario,
                nombre = n.nombre,
                nombreUsuario = n.nombreUsuario,
                email = n.email
            });

            DataSourceResult result = rest.ToDataSourceResult(request);

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

and this is the JSON result

```
{"Data":[{"idUsuario":1,"nombre":"Eduardo","nombreUsuario":"Brakyo","email":"eduardomeji@gmail.com"}],"Total":1,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}
```

i hope anyone can helpme.
Tankx :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with below code snippet.

Below code will help you to bind your Data in DropDownList but it will not work Kendoui Grid. Means you have create two separate method for Grid and DropDownList.

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult UsuarioRead()
    {
        IQueryable<Usuario> products = CashControl.Usuario;
        var rest = products.Select(n => new
        {
            idUsuario = n.idUsuario,
            nombre = n.nombre,
            nombreUsuario = n.nombreUsuario,
            email = n.email
        });

        return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, srry for that, i have two methods, one from the grid and other to the DropDownList, the grid works fine, the problem is the DropDownList, doesn´t show data :/

Comment: Can you please provide both the methods?